How to underline in minted without impacting highlighting?
For a code review, I want to underline bad code, just like some IDEs would:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{minted}
% TODO ???
\newcommand\startunderline{} % bad code from here ...
\newcommand\stopunderline{}  % ... up to here
\begin{document}
The following contains bad code:
\mintinline[escapeinside=++]{tex}|Hello +\startunderline+\it+\stopunderline+ World|
\end{document}

The naïve solution does not work as intended, since it removes any highlighting that would naturally apply.
Also note that minted opens and closes groups all along, so using grouping for \startunderline and \stopunderline will not work.
Some ideas that could work:

Save the positions of \startunderline and \stopunderline like the soulpos package. Maybe one could actually employ that package?
Ad hoc solution: Add an argument to \startunderline to specify how long the underline shall be and do not use \stopunderline. Works as long as there are no line breaks and the length is known for sure.


Another possible approach: use tikzmarks to store the start and end of the line and draw it later

You could use tikzmark:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\newcounter{mymark}
\newcommand\startunderline{\stepcounter{mymark}\tikzmark{startmark-\themymark}} % bad code from here ...
\newcommand\stopunderline{\tikzmark{stopmark-\themymark}}  % ... up to here
\begin{document}
The following contains bad code:
\mintinline[escapeinside=++]{tex}|Hello +\startunderline+\it+\stopunderline+ World|

\tikz[overlay,remember picture]
 {\draw([yshift=-2pt]pic cs:startmark-1)--([yshift=-2pt]pic cs:stopmark-1);}
\end{document}



I wrote a little package using Ulrike Fischer’s idea and made it available on Codeberg. It works for me. Still if you need line breaks or multiple overlapping underlines you will need some extra work. Here is a standalone version of what I currently have:
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,decorations.pathmorphing}

\newcounter{souloverlay}

\newcommand\drawmarks{%
    \def\startmarkpos{souloverlay-start-\arabic{souloverlay}}%
    \def\stopmarkpos{souloverlay-stop-\arabic{souloverlay}}%
    \tikz[overlay,remember picture]%
}
\newcommand\startmark{%
    \stepcounter{souloverlay}%
    \tikzmark{souloverlay-start-\arabic{souloverlay}}%
    \drawmarks
}
\newcommand\stopmark{%
    \tikzmark{souloverlay-stop-\arabic{souloverlay}}%
    \drawmarks
}

\newcommand\startwarn{\startmark{}}
\newcommand\stopwarn{\stopmark{\draw[blue,decorate,decoration={snake,amplitude=.1ex,segment length=.4ex}]([yshift=-.5ex]pic cs:\startmarkpos)--([yshift=-.5ex]pic cs:\stopmarkpos)}}

\newcommand\starterror{\startmark{}}
\newcommand\stoperror{\stopmark{\draw[red,decorate,decoration={snake,amplitude=.1ex,segment length=.4ex}]([yshift=-.5ex]pic cs:\startmarkpos)--([yshift=-.5ex]pic cs:\stopmarkpos)}}

\newcommand\starthighlight{\startmark{\fill[yellow]([yshift=-.3em]pic cs:\startmarkpos) rectangle ([yshift=1em]pic cs:\stopmarkpos)}}
\newcommand\stophighlight{\stopmark{}}

\begin{document}
The following contains deprecated code:
\mintinline[escapeinside=++]{tex}|Hello +\startwarn+\it+\stopwarn+ World|.

This even erroneous code:
\mintinline[escapeinside=++]{tex}|Hello +\startwarn+\it+\stopwarn+ World+\starterror+\bfshape+\stoperror+!|

Now this is it:
\begin{minted}[escapeinside=++]{tex}
    Hello +\starthighlight+\itshape+\stophighlight+ World+\starthighlight+\bfseries+\stophighlight+!
\end{minted}

\end{document}


